# Best way to compare two huge arrays?

Tags: arrays, hash, compare

I'm tasked with having 1,000,000 cards in one input file having a market price and then having the same 1,000,000 cards with a higher price in another input file, and I have to compare both to compute the profit.

A nested for loop of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < marketPriceCards.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < priceListCards.size(); j++){
        compute profit
```

is O(n^2) which is way too long. I was thinking a hash table but how big would I have to make it? A prime number that's higher than 1000000?

Answer (score 0):

In Java the default load factor is 0.75, so you can create your hashtable at the size of:

`1.75 * <size of your data>`

and that should be a good start.

By the way, you didn't mention which language are you going to use. In case it's Java you should use HashMap - not Hashtable (just FYI).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wrote a nested loop since it can be done in one loop O(n).
As your data is recorded in a two big files you need to read them and you need to traverse whole of the both file since you need all numbers.
if the records was less than 100,000 I would suggest to load them both in to memory using mopen() however you have two big files and loading them both into memory is not a clever action. So here it is what I think you should do in case you have text files

```
cardsFile = fopen ("elapsed.dta", "rt"); 
priceFile = fopen ("elapsed.dta", "rt"); 
while(fgets(aCardline, 80, cardsFile) != NULL)
   {
      sscanf (aCardline, "%ld", &aCard);    

      fgets(aPriceline, 80, priceFile)
      sscanf (aCardline, "%ld", &aPrice);  
      printf ("Card :%s Price :%ld\n", aCard, aPrice,);
   }
```

I think you have to change the methods which return cards and prices
you may use buffers in case you need to elaborate more the data.

I personally like to store this size of data in a database.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hashtable is not a good Idea, since its going to be a big structure.